# iOS Number Pad with Hyphen with HTML Input Tag

Tags: iphone, html, ios, input, keyboard

On a web page form input field with pattern "[0-9]*" or "\d*", iOS can switch to a number pad for better usability:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1

However, for a zipcode field where users might enter in '-', a hyphen, I needed to change the pattern to something like this "[0-9-]".  But iOS then changes the number pad back to the full keyboard.

Is there a way to add the hyphen but keep the number pad?  I'm not developing an app, so I don't have the objective C methods.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: u will have create custom numpad for this

Comment: @Omar Adelhafith: I'll give "[0-9]-" a try and let you know!  Thanks!

Comment: @Safecase: Yea, I was hoping that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith: Finally got a chance to give "[0-9]-" a try and didn't work.  Bummers, but thanks for the suggestion!